# Overwatch Mercy Damage

Tags: pc, overwatch

**I'm curious to know if Mercy does more/faster healing if you aim at the teammate you are currently trying to heal?** 
Just how Winston does AOE damage but you still have to aim to do full damage. Does anyone know?

Comment: I don't think you have to do much aiming with Winston's Tesla Cannon.  Or, at least, you only have to keep the enemy anywhere near-ish the center of your screen.

Comment: No. She doesn't even need full of line of sight to maintain the connection. So she can hide around corners somewhat after the beam connects. Same with amp beam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercy's beam does a flat 50 HP/s healing (or 60 if she's in Valkyrie), as per the [official wiki](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Mercy)